# how to use a url link to call a jquery

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink

In my website when user clicks on videos menu item, It calls a Jquery. Jquery contains ajax and it sends a request of which category video user clicked and as response it receives video files and show them in my website. Now what I want is how can I give someone to see all videos within my website by giving them a URL. When click the URL, they should be seen the all videos in the page. Is it possible to do?

content of videos.php
Jquery is as follows,

```
$j("#sunday").click(function(){

            var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
            var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
            var total_groups = <?php echo $total_sunday_groups; ?>; //total record group(s)
            var code="<div id=\"container2\"><div id=\"vid_pge_num\">";
             var j=0;
             for(var i=0; i<total_groups;i++)
             {
             j= i + 1;
             code= code + "<div class=\"num_box\" onclick=\"vid_page('"+j+"','1');\">"+j+"</div>";
             }
             code= code + "</div></div>";
             $j("#content").html(code);
             var cat='1';
             $j.post('get_recent_videos.php',{'group_no': track_load,'catogory':cat}, function(data){

             $j("#container2").append(data); //append received data into the element

             }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

             alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
             //$('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
             loading = false;

             });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **sammy.js** (http://sammyjs.org/). You create links like http://localhost.com/#/videos and then with sammy.js you write the URL routing rules and you run whatever jquery - javascript code you want when user visits them. Check their website and/or other websites for tutorials on sammy.js.